# Use iterparse and, subsequently, xpath on documents with inconsistent namespace declarations

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, xml-namespaces, iterparse

I need to put together a piece of code that parses a possibly large XML file into custom Python objects. The idea is roughly the following:

```py
from lxml import etree
for e, tag in etree.iterparse(source, tag='Foo'):
    print tag.xpath('bar/baz')[42] # there's actually a function call here
```

The problem is, some of the documents have a namespace declaration, and some don't have any. That means that in the code above both `tag='Foo'` and `xpath` parts won't work.

For now I've been putting up with the ugly

```py
for e, tag in etree.iterparse(source):
    if tag.tag.endswith('Foo'):
        print tag.xpath('*[local-name()="bar"]/*[local-name()="baz"]')[42]
```

but this is so awful that I want to get it right even though it works fine. (I guess it should be slower, too.)

Is there a way to write sane code that would account for both cases using `iterparse`?
For now I can only think of catching `start-ns` and `end-ns` events and updating a "state-keeping" variable, which I'll have to pass to the function that is called within the loop to do the work. The function will then construct the `xpath` queries accordingly. This makes some sense, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way around this.

P.S. I've obviously tried searching around, but haven't found a solution that would work both with and without a namespace. I would also accept a solution that eliminates namespaces from the XML, but only if it doesn't store the whole tree in RAM in the process.

Comment: Do elements passed in at start events include namespaces? Could you check those for the nsxml attributes?

Comment: LXML has the unfortunate limitation that it only supports XPath 1.0. In XPath 2.0, you could say `*:bar/*:baz`. Your check for `local-name()` is the [usual XPath 1.0 workaround](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/namespace-wildcards-in-xpath).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Namespace is either declared in the root or not declared at all. But I think you're right that I can check `tag.nsmap` on `end` events (did you mean `end`? this is what is caught by default). This leaves the `tag='Foo'` part unsolved, but seems easier overall. This may well be the best answer for the question.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: I meant start, you'd have to ask for start events too; but you are right, end will do. Namespaces *can* be declared on any element, btw.

Comment: @larsmans Thanks for the link, I'm a bit relieved. Still, having it 12 times in a file makes me sad.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: I'm afraid it's just the way it is. When parsing XML in Python (with LXML, or with the more space-efficient built-in ElementTree), I tend to build the path expressions dynamically after inspecting the root node for its namespace.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and larsmans: Guys, your comments have been of great help; too bad they're not answers so I can't upvote.

Comment: @LevLevitsky: I posted an answer, just for you. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Upvoted, just for myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements have a `.nsmap` mapping attribute; use it to detect your namespace and branch accordingly.